# Number of points in an equation

Tags: calculus

The number of points in $(- \infty, +\infty)$ for which $x^2-x\sin x - \cos x=0$ are ?
The answer is '2' but i am not sure how to proceed as the above equation is a mixture of polynomial and trignometric equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the function $f(x)=x^2-x\sin(x)-\cos(x)$. We can easily see that:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty}f(x)=+\infty \quad \text{and} \quad f(0)=-1$$

Now we want to study the first derivative of this function:

$$f'(x)=2x-x\cos(x)\quad  \text{which is positive} \quad \forall x > 0.$$

From this we can easily conclude that there are only two solutions for the [Bolzano's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html) and the monotony of the function (strictly increasing for $x > 0$ and viceversa for $x < 0$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stick to the half plane for my exmaple.

Set $f(x) = x^2 - x\sin x - \cos x$, for $x \ge 0$. Then clearly $f$ is a continuous functions with $f(0) = -1 < 0$ and $f(\pi) = \pi^2 + 1 > 0$. So by the intermediate value theorem, $f$ has a zero in $(0,\pi)$.

Now

$$f'(x) = 2x - x\cos x = x(2 - \cos x) \ge x(2 - 1) = x > 0$$

on $(0,\infty)$, $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$. Therefore, $f$ has only one root in $(0,\infty)$. Now apply a similar reasoning to $(- \infty, 0)$.